# Can I start implementing Game Center in my iPhone app, without having created a new app in iTunes connect?

Tags: iphone, game-center

I'm in the process of developing a game for the iPhone and I want to add Game Center support to it. The problem, as I see it, is that I need to have named my app, created an icon and uploaded screenshots etc. before I can create a leaderboard and start implementation?

My game is unfinished and the iTunes Connect developer guide seems to indicate that certain information can't be edited once entered. Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a new App to iTunes Connect in order to use Game Center.

However, all of the data can be bogus (it just needs to be valid) and you can change it later. Except for the App's name if I remember correctly. If you need to change that, you can still simply create a new App with the desired name, and then transfer the Achievements and Leaderboards setup to the new App, which is a bit of work but nothing you can't do in an hour or so.

A lot of the restrictions about what you can't edit in hindsight is only in regards to an App that has been submitted and approved. That's when a few things get locked in, I think keywords being one of them. Even then you can submit an update of your App and you'll be able to change some of the App's data that's otherwise no longer editable.